# calculating distance between detected objects in one image

Tags: python, keras, image-segmentation, multitasking, unet-neural-network

I am segmenting 4 objects in some medical Images taken of the human eye and I am trying to use multi task learning and while segmenting this object, I need to calculate the distance(or pixels) between them. As I am looking in different papers, I couldn't find related work to predict distances between two objects in one image. Can you guide me to such related works if you know one or just give me some ideas that how it can be done?

I am using unet by keras.